# CDF of a Uniform probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to find **Cumulative distribution function (CDF)** of the following density function:

$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
  3/20 & \text{for } 2 \leq  x \leq 4 \\[8pt]
  4/20 & \text{for }4 < x \leq 6 \\[8pt]
  1/20 & \text{for }6 <  x \leq 12 \\[8pt]
 0 & otherwise
  \end{cases}$

I first found the corresponding areas by drawing the functions.

[image]

from CDF formula $F(X) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$, I tried as follow:

$ F(x)= \begin{cases}
  0  & \text{for }x <2 \\[8pt]
  \frac{x-2}{4-2} & \text{for }2 \leq  x \leq 4 \\[8pt]
  \frac{x-4}{6-4} + 0.3 & \text{for }4 <  x \leq 6 \\[8pt]
\frac{x-6}{12-6} + 0.7 & \text{for }6 < x \leq 12 \\[8pt]
 1 & \text{for } x > 12
  \end{cases}$

I am not sure, whether it is true or not? please correct me if it is not true.

Comment: Re the title, there is no "Uniform" PDF here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Find equation of line that connects $(2,0)$ and $(4,0.3)$

Find equation of line that connects $(4,0.3)$ and $(6,0.7)$

Find equation of line that connects $(6,0.7)$ and $(12,1)$

Comment: Interesting. I can find the line equations. Thanks. But, how did you come up to that? why should I place the cumulative area values to $y$ coordinate of the lines?

Comment: The picture that is based on the description of density $f$ makes it clear that $F(2)=0$, $F(4)=0.3$, $F(6)=0.7$ and $F(12)=1$. On the intervals $[2,4]$,$[4,6]$ and $[6,12]$ the density is constant. This indicates that on these intervals the CDF is linear.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is incorrect, you can test by inserting values of x, for example F(4)= 1. Just integrate the function piecewise, your formula does only work for a uniform distribution (not piecewise), you would have to adapt it as: $F(X)=c\,(x-a)$ where c is the partial probability e.g. 3/20.
$$
\int \frac{3}{20}\,dx = \frac{3\,x}{20} 
$$
and shift it accordingly:
$$
\frac{3\,\left(x-2\right)}{20}
$$